# Batch strings conversion

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, cmd

Please, tell me what is wrong in my batch-script? The task is to compare files names in the specific folder with an integer variable. There are two issues:

1. Files names consist of numbers and may contain spaces and leading zeroes (e.g. 01.cmd, 0 02.cmd, 0 0 3.cmd, e.t.c.), which, I suppose, have to be deleted for further comparison with an integer variable.
2. Convert files names variable from string type to integer to compare with an integer variable.

   Here is the text of the script:

   ```
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

   for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`dir /b C:\tmp`) do
    rem delete spaces in the files names
    echo %%i
    set i=%%i: =%
    echo %%i  &::this always returns me only the same file name

      rem int - is an integer variable to compare with
      rem in this way I tried to convert a file name to integer
     if %int% lss %%i set /a int=%%i: =% 2>nul
   ```

   In Linux Shell it would be much easy, but I'm not so familiar with batch scripting. And this script need to be run under Windows OS.

Comment: `(` missing after `do`, `)` missing at all. Typo?. Variable substitution `set var=%var:<search>=<replace>` does not work with `for` variables (`%%I`).

Comment: `for` variables are case-sensitive, so `%%i` and `%%I` are not the same; and substring substitution does not work with `%%i`; you need to use an interim variable; for instance: `set "filename=%%~nxi"`, `set "filename=!filename: =!"` (note the `!` which are needed to use delayed expansion); then use `!filename!` for the rest of the code...

Comment: @Stephan.
 I omit the brackets in this post, but I use them in my script, though it makes no difference, as for me.
 About variable substitution that doesn't work with `for` I didn't know this fact, as there is no such an information in help for `for`. :(

Comment: @aschipfl.
I knew that I have to use `!` in `set` statement, but didn't know how, as there is too little information in Windows help. Thank you for you suggestion.

Comment: @acd: well, it does make a difference. They are part of the syntax. How should `cmd` know where to end the loop without them?

Comment: @Stephan. Yes, Stephan, you're quite right. :) It does make a difference. It was another mistake in my script, which caused false result. And `%%I` instead of `%%i` in the text was a typo.

Comment: @acd, when you type `set /?` in command prompt, you will find a short example concerning delayed expansion (`!`) in the help text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename variable can have a "name only" specifier; %%~nf. I assume you would want to omit directory names. The resulting number is in the !NUM! variable.

@Stephan is correct that numbers with leading zeros are considered octal. I have revised the script to remove leading zeros.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /A:-D /B`) DO (
    SET "FN=%%~nf"
    SET "NSN=!FN: =!x"
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%s in ("!NSN!") DO (SET "NSN=%%s")
    SET "NSN=!NSN:~0,-1!"
    SET /A "NUM=!NSN!"

    ECHO NUM is !NUM!
)
```

Comment: @acd: are you sure? Numbers with leading zeros will be treated as octal numbers, where `08` and `09` are illegal and will lead to an error in `set /a`. You will have to remove leading zeros to let it work correctly.

Comment: @acd - Note that if you have files named `7.txt` and `007.txt`, they will all result in a NUM value of `7`.